# database url from tnsname.ora

Tags: java, sql, oracle, netbeans-7

I'm trying to connect to my local database

when I try the netbeans IDE give me this error :

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:oracle:oci:@d3do3a:1521:XE

this is my `tnsname.ora` file:

```
XE =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = d3do3a)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
)
)

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SID = PLSExtProc)
  (PRESENTATION = RO)
)
)
```

and this my main method :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Connection myConn =null;
    Statement myStmt =null;
    ResultSet myRs =null;

    String user ="doaa";
    String pass ="0563014554";
    try {
        myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:oci:@d3do3a:1521:XE" , user ,pass);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(NewDatabase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

please is my database url correct or what is the error ???

Comment: just checking but can you cannot with sql plus to the database with that ini ?

Comment: The `oci` driver requires a complete Oracle client, it's better to use the `thin` driver instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for JDBC to find your driver, it need you to do two things:

1. Add the driver jar file to your classpath.
2. Give it the appropriate URL.

The problem may be that you haven't added the driver jar to your classpath.

Comment: thanks man I just download the driver and update the url to this : jdbc:oracle:thin:@d3do3a:1521/XE